# Different editors for different volumes of one work of reference

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Please consider the following entry for a work of reference:

```
@reference{rlw,
 publisher = {{De Gruyter}},
 title = {Reallexikon der deutschen Literaturwissenschaft},
 subtitle = {Neubearbeitung des Reallexikons der deutschen Literaturgeschichte},
 shorttitle = {RLW},
 year = {2003},
 location = {Berlin/New York},
 edition = {3 Bde. 3., neubearb. Aufl. (1997-2003). Bd. I (1997) hrsg. v. Klaus Weimar u. a. Bd. II (2000) hrsg. v. Harald Fricke u. a. Bd. III (2003) hrsg. v. Jan-Dirk M{\"u}ller u. a.},
 keywords = {lex}
}
```

This is a very hacky way to present a three volume work, and I needed to fiddle with the bibdriver to display it "properly"

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{reference}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \iffieldundef{shorttitle}
        {}%
        {\printfield{shorttitle} =}%
    \iffieldundef{editor}
        {}{
        \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
        \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
        }
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Example of bibliography entries]

The MLLK entry is just ornamental to show a "properly" defined entry alongside the entry in question. And never mind the leading abbreviation and equals sign, that has to do with [another question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448923/custom-bibliography-style-for-reference-and-inreference-with-custom-sorting).
What I was wondering is the following:
 - To have everything watertight I would need to mak a bib-entry for every volume so I could specify each volumes editor(s) separately
 - That would bloat my Bibliography quite a bit, because in this case I would have 3 different entries
 - Although being different, these three entries still needed to be summed up under one abbreviation, because one would refer to the whole work as "RLW" and not one single volume
 - Which volume is cited speciffically is given in the child-entry (working with crossref)

Is there a way to specify a work as `@reference` (as I did with the custom display), but have three different entries (that ideally can be crossreffed, and themselves crossref the @ThisIsAnEntryForTheWholeShelfInTheLibraryTheseBooksRestOn) appear directly under (preferably indented) this master-entry?
I don't so much worry about the crossref-part for the individual articles to individual volumes, that is working already. I'm rather looking for a nice way to list seperate volumes of one work under its "master entry".
Quick mockup in Word:
[image: Mockup for desired result]

Comment: You want the `related` and `relatedtype` fields. Have a look at the `knuth:ct:related` entry in `biblatex-examples.bib`, which lays things out similar to what you want. You'd need to customise the `related:multivolume` macro to get things looking exactly like what you want, as well as further tweaking your `reference` driver. The only caveat is that you would need to switch away from `bibtex8` to `biber`. This is a good idea anyway. `bibtex` only supports a subset of features from `biblatex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started, but will likely need further customisation.

I've used the `related` field and `relatedtype={multivolume}` to set up the relationship between the master multivolume entry and each volume. I've redefine the `related:multivolume` macro to print each volume in the format you want.

I've also made a few other changes to your `reference` driver so that you don't have to put everything in the `edition` field.

And I modified the list delimiter for the `location`, so you can use the correct `location = {Berlin and New York}` rather than the incorrect `location = {Berlin/New York}`. The extra braces around De Gruyter are not necessary. And I've used the `biblatex` `date` field which allows for date ranges to be properly specified.

**Note:** You must you `biber`, not `bibtex(8)` for this example to work. Specifically related entries are not supported by `bibtex`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvreference{rlw,
 title = {Reallexikon der deutschen Literaturwissenschaft},
 subtitle = {Neubearbeitung des Reallexikons der deutschen Literaturgeschichte},
 shorttitle = {RLW},
 volumes = {3},
 edition = {3\addcomma\space\bibstring{revision}\space\bibstring{edition}},
 location = {Berlin and New York},
 publisher = {De Gruyter},
 date = {1997/2003},
 keywords = {lex},
 related = {rlw:1,rlw:2,rlw:3},
 relatedtype = {multivolume}
}
@reference{rlw:1,
  title = {A--G},
  editor = {Weiman, Klaus and others},
  volume = {I},
  date = {1997},
  crossref = {rlw}
}
@reference{rlw:2,
  title = {H--O},
  editor = {Fricke, Harald and others},
  volume = {II},
  date = {2000},
  crossref = {rlw}
}
@reference{rlw:3,
  title = {P--Z},
  editor = {M\"uller, Jan-Dirk and others},
  volume = {III},
  date = {2003},
  crossref = {rlw}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multilistdelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finallistdelim}{\slash}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{reference}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdate}% ← treat dates specially for references
  \iffieldundef{shorttitle}
    {}%
    {\printfield{shorttitle}\printtext{ = }}%
  \iffieldundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
     \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{related:multivolume}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \printtext{%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \printfield{part}}%
    \setunit*{\space}%
    \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    \setunit*{\space}%
    \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{title}}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnamesequal{author}{savedauthor}}
      or
      test {\ifnameundef{author}}
    }
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{author}{author}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printnames[byauthor]{author}
       \newunit\newblock}%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnamesequal{editor}{savededitor}}
      or
      test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
    }
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock}}}

\NewBibliographyString{revision}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  byeditor = {hrsg\adddotspace v\adddot},
  revision = {neubearb\adddot},
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you! (switching to biber was overdue anyway...)